# Align background image in span with display as table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a following `display:table` structure and I have two spans in a div set as `display: table-cell` in div `table-row` as `display:table-row`  as follows:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-row1">
        <span class="table-cell">text1</span>
        <span class="table-cell">text2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row2">
        <span class="table-cell">text1</span>
        <span class="table-cell">text2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want an icon as background image to displayed in text1 span in `table-row2` div. The length of text in span is dynamic. I want the icon to be aligned with start of the text. Any help is appreciated.

the span of text1 has following css:

```
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: right;
    width:50%;
}
```

Also the icon is conditional and different icon shows up on different condition based on the data received to the component.

Comment: Is the icon displayed only in text 1 `<span>`, or in all four `<span>` elements?

Comment: just in the `text1` span in the `table-row2`

Answer (score 0):

Use the icon `<i>` element and add the background image to the `before` pseudo element like so:

```
i::before {
  content: url(path_to_file.ext);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

In the `i` element, make sure to define the width and height. Since you will be adding the content via CSS you need to set fixed dimensional values. Additionally, for alignment purposes it is a good idea to use flex like so:

```
i {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: The icon is conditional depending upon the data. Sorry I missed it, I have updated the description. This will work with only one icon.